# unziping '.DBL' files in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip

I'm trying to unzip huge DBL files in my Google drive via Google Colab but it does not recognize them as Zip files.

```
!unzip -n /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Raw_data/S10/Unziped//VE_VM01_VSC_L2VALD_ISRAES10_20200310.DBL -d /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Relevant_images/S10/
```

I have got this output:

```
Archive:  /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Raw_data/S10/Unziped//VE_VM01_VSC_L2VALD_ISRAES10_20190115.DBL
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Raw_data/S10/Unziped//VE_VM01_VSC_L2VALD_ISRAES10_20190115.DBL or
        /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Raw_data/S10/Unziped//VE_VM01_VSC_L2VALD_ISRAES10_20190115.DBL.zip, and cannot find /content/drive/MyDrive/floods_images/5Projects/Venus_for_flood/Images/Raw_data/S10/Unziped//VE_VM01_VSC_L2VALD_ISRAES10_20190115.DBL.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: What do you expect to find in a `.DBL` file? Where do they come from?

Comment: Its a file with satellite scenes files including Tiff and txt  files

Comment: What tool do you normally open them with, outside of Colab? What program creates them? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with `!p7zip ...` on Colab?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. System ERROR:
E_FAIL

Comment: Have you tried with `!7z ...` ?

Comment: I got this error: Unknown error -2147024868

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0